# Java: Moving large files from one folder to another using FileUtils

Tags: java, filesystems, fileutils

I have a Java web application running on a Tomcat application server on a Windows machine that downloads files from a sFTP server in zip format. Next it unzips the files to an unzipped folder and finally it copies the files to an incoming folder where they are waiting to be processed. The files are very large (+1Gb)

The problem I have is with moving the files from the unzipped folder to the incoming folder:
I'm using Apache FileUtils to move all the content of one directory to another in Java:

```
public static List<String> moveFolderContent(File incomingFolder, File destinationFolder) throws IOException {
    List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final File fileEntry : incomingFolder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            moveFolderContent(fileEntry, destinationFolder);
        } else {
            errorList.add(fileEntry.getName());
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(fileEntry, destinationFolder);
            FileUtils.forceDelete(fileEntry);
        }
    }
    return errorList;
}
```

However I get following exception:

```
06-12-2017 | 06:01:52,188 | ERROR | TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler  | Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: S:\Pwg\individuals\unzipped\Snapshot_professional_nurse_v16.xml
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2279)
```

I looks like the original File is still in use, while I would expect that the FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory method finishes when the copy process is finished, releasing the lock on both files and then proceeds to the forceDelete method...

I also tried with:

```
FileUtils.copymoveFileToDirectory(fileEntry, destinationFolder, false);
```

which is maybe cleaner, but this gave me the exact same exception :(

Comment: why do you unzip first and move then? i think it would be somewhat better to first move and then unzip because you have less copy time. maybe you can release the lock with [this api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html)

Comment: Consider an external lock (virus scanner). You can use the "resource monitor" of windows to check access to a file. Or check if the unpack process closed all file handles/streams.